# How long does Glibc take to compile?

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, glibc

I've been compiling it in a virtual machine for over 8 hours now and it still hasn't finished.

The terminal is still printing things so I know it's still compiling.

The host system is a 2.10Ghz Intel Core2Duo with 4GB RAM and the guest is Linux on a PowerPC virtual machine (QEMU) one with 1GB RAM.

I know the dynamic instruction translation can slow things down a bit but even so, Glibc shouldn't take longer than 3 hours or so?

Is there something wrong or should I just continue to let do it's thing overnight?

Comment: Dynamic translation slows down such processes **a lot**. And Glibc is a huge piece of software. Therefore the result will be near endless compile times. Why don't you simply cross-compile on the Intel host for a PowerPC target? That's probably much faster.

Comment: Thing is. I'm building a cross Linux from scratch system and it says I must continue the installation on a PowerPC machine. Since the only one I have at hand is a 15 year old PowerBook I figured it'll be faster if I ran it from a virtual machine.

Comment: over 4 hours for glibc 2.24 on nehalem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For comparison, the last time Ubuntu compiled eglibc for a 64-bit machines, it took [about 1.75 hours for amd64](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/2.12-0ubuntu4/+build/1814808), and [about 2.5 hours for both i386](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/2.12-0ubuntu4/+build/1814810) and [powerpc](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/2.12-0ubuntu4/+build/1814812)

I think it's just that dynamic translation is that slow, especially dynamic translation to a different architecture.

Comment: From the same link, I looked up the compile times for uClibc and they were way shorter.

Would using uClibc be a better option in this instance?